# javascript date difference NaN

Tags: javascript

In the following code i get the `course_diff_date` as NaN what am i doing wrong here, i want to get the difference in days

```
console.log(d1);
//Thu Jan 01 1970 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
var today = new Date(); 
var course_time = new Date(d1);
var new_date = new Date(today.getMonth()+ "/" +today.getDate()+ "/" +today.getFullYear());
var server_date = new Date(course_time.getMonth()+ "/" +course_time.getDate()+ "/" +course_time.getFullYear());
var timeDiff = Math.round(new_date.getTime() - server_date.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
course_diff_date = diffDays + " Days";
```

Comment: I have coreected the code time.time Please check the result is still NaN

Comment: what is the value of d1? Is it a string or date?

Comment: d1 is a date not a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `date.getTime()` instead:

**EDIT**

```js
var daysTillNow = function(str) {
  var today = new Date();
  //time stamp is taken for testing
  var course_time = new Date(str);
  //difference in mili seconds
  var diff = today.getTime() - course_time.getTime();
  //round off mili-sec to days
  diff = Math.round(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return diff + " day(s)";
};


console.log(daysTillNow('Thu Dec 11 2014 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)')); //11 days
console.log(daysTillNow('Mon Dec 22 2014 11:13:21 GMT+0530 (IST)')); //0 days
```

```html
open console... F12
```

Comment: with ur code snippet this is what i tried  var today = new Date(); var server_launchtime = new Date("Mon Dec 22 2014 11:13:21 GMT+0530 (IST)"); var diff = today.getTime() - server_launchtime.getTime(); gives me 9578345 Days

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
course_time.time.getMonth()
```

use:

```
course_time.getMonth()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra .time on

```
var server_date = new Date(course_time.time.getMonth()+ "/" +course_time.getDate()+ "/" +course_time.getFullYear());
```

It should be

```
var server_date = new Date(course_time.getMonth()+ "/" +course_time.getDate()+ "/" +course_time.getFullYear());
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be course_time instead of course_time.time

```
d1 = "12 January 2014";
d1 = new Date(d1);
var today = new Date(); 
var course_time = new Date(d1);
var new_date = new Date(today.getMonth()+ "/" +today.getDate()+ "/" +today.getFullYear());
var server_date = new Date(course_time.getMonth()+ "/" +course_time.getDate()+ "/" +course_time.getFullYear());
var timeDiff = Math.round(new_date.getTime() - server_date.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
course_diff_date = diffDays + " Days";
```